# Jmeter Newbie: Results Tree displays several results for single login GET

Tags: jmeter, treeview, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to Jmeter so forgive if this potentially dumb question but why does a single Login GET request when ran displays 20 results in the results tree? See screenshots for details. I'm using Blazemeter plugin to record the script.

- Jmeter version 5.1.1 r1855137
- Blazemeter plugin v 4.7.1
- Chrome latest version

HTTP request

[image: Results Tree]

Comment: What is your thread number and loop and duration (if exists)?

Comment: Number of Threads = 1 Loop Count = 1

Answer (score 0):

This is due to so called "embedded resources", more or less each page apart from main HTML content includes additional content like:

- images
- scripts
- styles
- fonts
- etc.

So each of your `Login QA Product GET - X` request stands for the "embedded resource" call for a picture or a JavaScript file.

The behaviour is controllable via "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" box at the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

The impact:

[image]

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - does the HTTP Request Defaults setting for retrieving embedded resources override the Sampler setting for retrieving embedded resources ?